# SHOGUN on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, shogun

What's the best way to get the latest SHOGUN / Python modular interface (http://www.shogun-toolbox.org) installed on 12.04? I tried from source without much luck (happy to post errors); Is it possible to install the Trusty Tahr package on 12.04? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shogun/3.1.1-1

Answer (score 3):

(I am the debian maintainer of this package).

You could try to

`apt-get -b source shogun`

but it will give you only the core libshogun library at this very moment. There is a python package on the way (in debian) but not yet accepted and not yet in ubuntu.

https://ftp-master.debian.org/new/python-shogun_3.1.1-1.html

So you are really best of installing from source. Shogun has buildbots running on ubuntu creating a python package. So you can just copy the settings from there:

https://travis-ci.org/shogun-toolbox/shogun/jobs/18605663

Comment: So...I never got this to work. I am trying again, still on 12.04. I downloaded 3.2.0, tried to follow the directions here (http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/current/installation.html) which seem wrong (there's no configure!) then I found these: http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/latest/install.html . cmake works, but then make dies with: /home/ubuntu/shogun-3.2.0/src/shogun/statistics/TestStatistic.cpp:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

Comment: ubuntu@ok2:~/shogun-3.2.0/build$ uname -a
Linux ok2.novalocal 3.2.0-24-virtual #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 18:44:18 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: For those following along at home, I finally got this working on Ubuntu 14.04...more details are here: http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/irclogs/%23shogun.2014-09-12.log.html

Comment: Here is what i tried:
1 .downloaded shogun 3.0 and unpacked it
2. cd shogun
3. mkdir build
4. cd shogun
5. cmake -DBUNDLE_JSON=ON -DBUNDLE_EIGN3=ON -DPythonModular=ON -DENABLE_TESTING=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/plagtag/anaconda ..
6. make -j4 #four processes takes a while
7. make install

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.machine-learning.shogun/4825) posts here and this [instruction](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/wiki/QUICKSTART) i did the following that worked for me to install shogun directly into my conda env. Its not the most elegant way but worked out so far.

! Take care to have swig: ie. installed apt-get install swig
! I used anaconda and the shogun python infterface - so my cmake prefix was /home/user/anaconda/

You need cmake to build shogun:

SET UP CMAKE FIRST (skip if you have cmake > 3.1)

1. cd /path to your installation directory
2. workdir=$(pwd) #i.e. your home
3. Download and install cmake into your home:
4. wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.1/cmake-3.1.3.tar.gz
5. tar xzf cmake-3.1.3.tar.gz
6. cd cmake-3.1.3
7. cmake_dir=$workdir/cmake 5 ./configure --prefix=$cmake_dir
8. make -j 2
9. make install
10. Export cmake to your PATH so you can use it for shogun:  export
     PATH=$cmake_dir/bin/:$PATH

Download and install shogun into anaconda env

1. wget ftp://shogun-toolbox.org/shogun/releases/3.1/sources/shogun-3.1.1.tar.bz2
2. tar jxf shogun-3.1.1.tar.bz2  3 cd shogun-3.1.1/
3. mkdir build
4. cd build
5. cmake -DPythonStatic=ON -DPythonModular=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda/envs/p27/ ..
6. make -j2 all #four processes takes a while
7. make install

Comment: On step 5 of the shogun install, would just DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/myusername/anaconda/ work (no envs/p27/ ..) ?